# Factory pattern, implementing a dynamic list of factories

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

I'm implementing an abstract factory pattern (in c++), but there is a slight problem.

I'd like to avoid creating a place which must know at compile time what factories exist.

Usually in the examples I see something like this.

```
Factory * getFactory()
{
    if(/*we should make factoryA*/)
    {
        return FactoryA::instance();
    }
    else if(/*we should return FactoryB*/)
    {
        return FactoryB::instance();
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I could do something like this, but I want better!

What I have in mind is that the Factory base class would have a list of Factories, each class inherited from *Factory* would create a static instance and add that instance to the list, through a protected class function in *Factory*.

However, I can't figure out a way to do this without playing Russian Roulette with static object initialization.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How do you decide which Factory should be returned? Why do you want a list, how would you pull the correct factory out of the list?

Comment: What does FactoryA::instance() return? Does it return an instance of a factory? Does it return an instance of a new A? My first glance at your code made me think that the function was returning factories. If this is the case, your approach is probably wrong.

Comment: @dauphic: This is relatively standard pattern. You have a bunch of factory objects and you need to decide dynamically at run-time which to use.

Comment: What scares you about `Russian Roulette`. Show us the code and maybe we can suggest how to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing Simple:

```
class BaseFactory
{
    public:
        BaseFactory()
        {
           std::list<BaseFactory*>&  fList = getFactoryList();
           fList.push_back(this);

           // If you are feeling brave.
           // Write the destructor to remove the object from the list.
           //
           // Note C++ guarantees the list will live longer than any of the factories
           // Because the list will always be completely constructed before any
           // of the factory objects (because we get the list in the constructor).
        }

        static BaseFactory& getFactory()  // Don't return a pointer (use a reference)
        {
           std::list<BaseFactory*>&  fList = getFactoryList();
           std::list<BaseFactory*>::iterator i = selectFactory(fList);

           if (i == fList.end()
           {
               static FakeFactory  fakeFactory; // Having a fake factory that
                                                // that returns fake object
                                                // is usually a lot easier than checking for
                                                // NULL factory objects everywhere in the code
                                                //
                                                // Alternatively throw an exception.
               return fakeFactory;
           }

           return *(*i); // return reference
        }
    private:
        static std::list<BaseFactory*>& getFactoryList()
        {
            static std::list<BaseFactory*>  factoryList; // Notice the static
            return factoryList;
        }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Is this correct(?): static variables declared in functions are guaranteed to be instantiated when the function is entered, even in the case when a function is entered from the initialization of a static object?

Comment: An object is fully constructed once its constructor completes. Static storage duration (globals/static function scope objects) objects are maintained in the order they are created (completion of constructor) and destroyed in reverse order of creation (this is all guaranteed by the standard).The order of global objects is a bit vague but static function objects are initialized on first use.Thus if a global object calls a function with static object from its constructor this object will be fully constructed before the globals constructor is complete and thus will have been constructed first

Comment: will `this` work, when `Factory` has multiple inheritance and `BaseFactory` is not the first base class?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid problems with static initialization order, you can make the list a static member of a function getFactoryList().  This will then ensure that the list exists when the protected constructor needs to add a factory to the list.

You'll then want to add a virtual method to Factory to determine if a given factory should be used.  Hopefully only one factory is eligible for use at a time, so that the order that the factories got created does not change which factory is returned.

Answer (score 0):

How would you benefit form such design? I mean, even when you had that list,  you would have to select that factory somehow, based on some criteria.

Try [Inversion Of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) pattern instead.

If Class A needs to create an object, pass factory to that class.

```
class A {
    Factory *f;
 public:
    A(Factory *f)
       : f(f)
    {  }

    void doSomething()
    {
       Object o = f->produce();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you would decide which factory to use on the "higher level". Factory may came form the source, form plugin etc.

Comment: The question is about selecting the factory. You are one step ahead where you have selected the factory and passed the factory to the object. Before you can do this you need to get the factory.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pattern to collect instances of subclasses.  This is the bare bones of it couched in terms of a factory:

```
class Factory {
    public:
      virtual Foo* makeFoo()=0;
      ...
    protected:
      Factory(){
          getFactoryList().push_back(this);
      }
    private:
      FactoryList& getFactoryList();  // Returns static list
};

class FactoryA: public Factory{
      Foo* makeFoo();  // I make a Foo my way
} FACTORYINSTANCE;
```

You still need a way of searching the list for the correct factory to use, and my macro FACTORYINSTANCE just evaluates to a unique name in order to invoke its own constructor.